# wildcard in expect script doesn't work

Tags: testing, expect

I have the following script running successfully. However if I try to use a wildcard, to copy multiple files, it throws an error, saying “No such file or directory”.

This code works:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn scp file1.txt root@192.168.1.156:/temp1/.
expect "password:"
send "iamroot\r"
expect "*\r"
expect "\r"
```

The following doesn't work:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn scp * root@192.168.1.156:/temp/. #fails here
….
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `*` is usually expanded by the shell (bash), but in this case you shell is `expect`. I suspect that `expect` is not expanding the `*`.

try:

```
spawn bash -c 'scp * root@192.168.1.156:/temp/.'
```

explanation:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn echo *
expect "*"

spawn bash -c 'echo *'
expect "file1 file2…"
```

Comment: I would add that sometimes you might even want `{}` to make sure nothing is captured by Tcl (in you have options or else.)

Comment: Use double quotes if you are using any variables in the command.

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK scp defaults to file copy while bash might expand * to directories also, if any is found in the current path.

Perhaps trying a `-r` (recursive) could solve your problem (not sure as I can't test the scenario right now)?

Or if you do not want to copy the whole folder structure, you could use `scp *.txt ...` depending on your needs.

Comment: Precisely my point, bash does the * expansion and in his case there is no such thing. Also my knowledge of SCP is that by default it copies only files, and spcifying the `-r` would recursively copy the entire folder structure, if that is what he needs. I might have missed my point with the `*.txt` but I wouldn't down-vote it. Cheers!